# EventEmitter error after updating to NPM 3.10

Tags: node.js, npm

I have updated NPM and now my code is returning the following error (please see picture):

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWesg.png) can someone please provide guidance in identifying the culprit?  My suspicion is that it has to do with inheritss which I'm not familiar with.

```
/**
* Expose the constructor.
*/

exports = module.exports = Store;

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var EventEmitter = process.EventEmitter;

/**
 * Store interface
 *
 * @api public
 */

function Store (options) {
  this.options = options;
  this.clients = {};
};

/**
 * Inherit from EventEmitter.
 */

Store.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;

/**
 * Initializes a client store
 *
 * @param {String} id
 * @api public
 */

Store.prototype.client = function (id) {
  if (!this.clients[id]) {
    this.clients[id] = new (this.constructor.Client)(this, id);
  }

  return this.clients[id];
};

/**
 * Destroys a client
 *
 * @api {String} sid
 * @param {Number} number of seconds to expire client data
 * @api private
 */

Store.prototype.destroyClient = function (id, expiration) {
  if (this.clients[id]) {
    this.clients[id].destroy(expiration);
    delete this.clients[id];
  }

  return this;
};

/**
 * Destroys the store
 *
 * @param {Number} number of seconds to expire client data
 * @api private
 */

Store.prototype.destroy = function (clientExpiration) {
  var keys = Object.keys(this.clients)
    , count = keys.length;

  for (var i = 0, l = count; i < l; i++) {
    this.destroyClient(keys[i], clientExpiration);
  }

  this.clients = {};

  return this;
};

/**
 * Client.
 *
 * @api public
 */

Store.Client = function (store, id) {
  this.store = store;
  this.id = id;
};
```

Comment: Didn't you also get a deprecation warning, _"process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead."_?

Comment: No warning, thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The current way to get the EventEmitter class is:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
```

You should not be using `process.EventEmitter`.

---

In addition, the modern way to subclass an object is using either the ES6 `class` syntax or using `Object.create()`, not using `__proto__`.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance was able to fix the problem. :)

Comment: @user2832956 - Since it appears you may be new here, if this answer helped you solve your issue, then you can indicate that to the community by marking this as the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will also earn you some reputation points on the site for following the proper procedure.